# How can I get the logged user in tastypie?

Tags: django, tastypie

I want to get the logged user in the dehydrate method of the class derived from ModelResource in Tastypie.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. There is request object in bundle;

```
def dehydrate(self,bundle):
    logged_user = bundle.request.user
    ...
    return bundle
```

This works fine.